# Exception while trying to iterate a navigation propery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, console-application, navigation-properties

I got a console app with EF on VS2013 and I got 2 models:

```
 public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public Student()
    {
        Subjects = new List<Subject>();
    }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public Subject()
    {
        Student = new Student();
    }
}
```

Plus, I got a DB context for them. I am able to update the DB and view my tables , but I am unable to iterate on the navigation properties... For example:
[image: The exception I get]

What am I doing wrong ?

This is my EF version:
[image: My EF version]

Comment: what does the inner exception say?

Comment: Why are you creating a student when you construct a Subject but when you construct a student it creates new subjects?  Seems very circular, which could be a problem?

Comment: Until you show the inner exception this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code instead:

```
IList<Student> studs = db.Students.Include("Subjects").ToList();

foreach (var _stud in studs) {
  foreach (var sub in _stud.Subject){

}
}
```

It's the lazy loading feature. U can take the constructors out

Comment: There's no reason to assume that lazy loading can't occur. Moreover, it would generate a different exception.